# Olimex monitor should be 800x480; is 656x512, yes overscan is on

Tags: hdmi, video

One of these 7-inch babies followed me home:

https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A13/A13-LCD7-TS/resources/S700-AT070TN92.pdf

When I assemble the micromonitor, the RPi2 boots right up, and `startx` works. But...

The display configurator says the monitor is 656x512, contradicting that PDF. The pixels are fuzzy, because 512 framebuffer scanlines > 480 LCD scanlines. And the active area has a black 8-millimeter border, which loses me several square centimeters of area.

Did I mention I turned on overscan and the problem did the opposite of go away? Also `raspi-config` won't tell me if it thinks the switch is on.

What's the next step in basic 7-inch LCD TLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to specify hdmi mode in config.txt to force Rpi to a certain resolution.

Follow these steps :

1. sudo nano /boot/config.txt
2. locate following line.

   > Uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA).
3. Add these lines below it to force 800x480 custom mode.

   ```
   disable_overscan=1
   hdmi_group=2
   hdmi_mode=87
   hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
   ```

ctrl+o to write, and ctrl+x to exit.

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope it helps.

Also have a look at this link for other HDMI modes.

http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: More documentation about that here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md

Comment: Tx! It worked so well I'm a little overscanned now. No biggie!

Comment: Edited my answer. Add this line : "disable_overscan=1" over hdmi_group=2

Comment: I know this answer is 3 years old at least and I tried this answer on my PI 3 connected to Adafruit 7inch display. Now, it totally disabled the display. It won't even turn on. I need to somehow get to the Config.txt and reset it or I will have to REDO my PI 3 all together... that is going to suck! lol...

Comment: @ThN: You can plug the sd card on your computer and make changes to config.txt.

Comment: @dhruvvyas90 Thank you. Yes, I think I have to do that. The reason your answer won't work for me is because of the `hdmi_mode` value 87. I looked through the wiki list for hdmi mode and it only goes up to 86.

Comment: @ThN: `hdmi_mode` value 87 is for custom resolutions. See this. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=24679

Comment: @dhruvvyas90 OOPS! My bad. I didn't enter the `hdmi_cvt` correctly. all I had was `hdmi 800 480 60 6 0 0 0`. Once I made the correction, now my whole adafruit display is filled with the raspbian desktop. AWESOME!!! Thank you.

Comment: @ThN: Glad that you were able to solve it. :)